# Segmentation Fault при завершении скрипта на lua

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

Написал небольшой модуль для `lua5.1` (в качестве эксперимента) на с++ (понятное дело функции экспортированы в `C`). Модуль предоставляет объект массив чисел с такими операциями как: получить размер, установить значение, получить значение по индексу. Все просто, все понятно. Вот код:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>

#define ARRAY_META "levkovitch.array"

#pragma pack(1)
class LuaArray final {
public:
  size_t size() const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(ptr_);
  }
  float &operator[](int i) {
    return (reinterpret_cast<float *>(ptr_) + sizeof(size_t))[i];
  }
  LuaArray(void *ptr)
      : ptr_{ptr} {
  }
  void setSize(size_t size) {
    *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(ptr_) = size;
  }

private:
  void *ptr_;
};

extern "C" {
/**\brief create new array of floats with given size
 */
int lua_newarray(::lua_State *state) {
  int size = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 1);
  luaL_argcheck(state, size > 0, 1, "have to be number > 0");
  LuaArray data =
      ::lua_newuserdata(state, sizeof(LuaArray) + size * sizeof(float));
  data.setSize(size);

  luaL_getmetatable(state, ARRAY_META);
  ::lua_setmetatable(state, -2);
  return 1;
}

int lua_sizearray(::lua_State *state) {
  LuaArray arr = ::luaL_checkudata(state, 1, ARRAY_META);
  ::lua_pushnumber(state, arr.size());
  return 1;
}

int lua_setvalue(::lua_State *state) {
  LuaArray arr   = ::luaL_checkudata(state, 1, ARRAY_META);
  int      index = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 2);
  float    val   = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 3);
  luaL_argcheck(state, index > 0 && index <= (int)arr.size(), 2, "wrong index");
  arr[index] = val;
  return 0;
}

int lua_getvalue(::lua_State *state) {
  LuaArray arr   = ::lua_touserdata(state, 1);
  int      index = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 2);
  luaL_argcheck(state, index > 0 && index <= (int)arr.size(), 2, "wrong index");
  ::lua_pushnumber(state, arr[index]);
  return 1;
}

static const ::luaL_Reg arrayFuncs[] = {
    {"new", lua_newarray},
    {nullptr, nullptr},
};

static const ::luaL_Reg arrayMembers[] = {
    {"getval", lua_getvalue},
    {"setval", lua_setvalue},
    {"size", lua_sizearray},
    {nullptr, nullptr},
};

int luaopen_array(::lua_State *state) {
  ::luaL_newmetatable(state, ARRAY_META);
  ::lua_pushvalue(state, -1);
  ::lua_setfield(state, -2, "__index");
  ::luaL_openlib(state, nullptr, arrayMembers, 0);

  ::luaL_openlib(state, "array", arrayFuncs, 0);
  return 1;
}
}
```

lua

```
local array = require("array")

local function main()
  local arr = array.new(10)
  if not arr then
    print("invalid arr")
  end

  for i = 1, arr:size() do
    arr:setval(i, i * 2)
  end

  for i = 1, arr:size() do
    print(arr:getval(i))
  end
end

main()
```

Все работает как и ожидалось, но возникли проблемы, когда я переделал код для доступа к вышеперечисленным методам через `__len`, `__index`, `__newindex` поля метадаблицы:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>

#define ARRAY_META "levkovitch.array"

#pragma pack(1)
class LuaArray final {
public:
  size_t size() const {
    return *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(ptr_);
  }
  float &operator[](int i) {
    return (reinterpret_cast<float *>(ptr_) + sizeof(size_t))[i];
  }
  LuaArray(void *ptr)
      : ptr_{ptr} {
  }
  void setSize(size_t size) {
    *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(ptr_) = size;
  }

private:
  void *ptr_;
};

extern "C" {
/**\brief create new array of floats with given size
 */
int lua_newarray(::lua_State *state) {
  int size = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 1);
  luaL_argcheck(state, size > 0, 1, "have to be number > 0");
  LuaArray data =
      ::lua_newuserdata(state, sizeof(LuaArray) + size * sizeof(float));
  data.setSize(size);

  luaL_getmetatable(state, ARRAY_META);
  ::lua_setmetatable(state, -2);
  return 1;
}

int lua_sizearray(::lua_State *state) {
  LuaArray arr = ::luaL_checkudata(state, 1, ARRAY_META);
  ::lua_pushnumber(state, arr.size());
  return 1;
}

int lua_setvalue(::lua_State *state) {
  LuaArray arr   = ::luaL_checkudata(state, 1, ARRAY_META);
  int      index = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 2);
  float    val   = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 3);
  luaL_argcheck(state, index > 0 && index <= (int)arr.size(), 2, "wrong index");
  arr[index] = val;
  return 0;
}

int lua_getvalue(::lua_State *state) {
  LuaArray arr   = ::lua_touserdata(state, 1);
  int      index = ::luaL_checknumber(state, 2);
  luaL_argcheck(state, index > 0 && index <= (int)arr.size(), 2, "wrong index");
  ::lua_pushnumber(state, arr[index]);
  return 1;
}

static const ::luaL_Reg arrayFuncs[] = {
    {"new", lua_newarray},
    {nullptr, nullptr},
};

static const ::luaL_Reg arrayMembers[] = {
    {"__index", lua_getvalue},
    {"__newindex", lua_setvalue},
    {"__len", lua_sizearray},
    {nullptr, nullptr},
};

int luaopen_array(::lua_State *state) {
  ::luaL_newmetatable(state, ARRAY_META);
  ::luaL_openlib(state, nullptr, arrayMembers, 0);

  ::luaL_openlib(state, "array", arrayFuncs, 0);
  return 1;
}
}
```

lua

```
local array = require("array")

local function main()
  local arr = array.new(10)
  if not arr then
    print("invalid arr")
  end

  for i = 1, #arr do
    arr[i] = i * 2
  end

  for i = 1, #arr do
    print(arr[i])
  end
end

main()
```

Изменения минимальны и программа даже работает как ожидается до момента ее завершения, но падает при выходе. Почему? Предологаю, что дело в сборщике мусора, но что же все таки происходит?

PS когда ставлю `collectgarbage()` до цикла с присваиванием, скрипт завершается без ошибки,а если сразу после цикла с присваиванием, то на этом месте вылетает segmentation fault

Comment: Попробуйте отладить программу, бэктрэйс с GDB посмотрите, что где падает. В идеале бы мин. полный воспроизводимый пример получить, но и банальный бэктрейс сильно поможет.

Comment: @val я извиняюсь, но вы вопрос вообще читали? Что значит минимальной полностью воспроизводимый пример? А код, который я привел? Что это по вашему?

Comment: По его размеру мне показалось, что он что-то не очень минимальный, да и C++/Lua код разделён не был (на будущее, ruSO теперь поддерживает ``` для более удобного форматирования кода). Ладно, пойду смотреть бэктрэйс.

Comment: @val по поводу разделения - это мой косяк, ну а что касается минимальности - меньше некуда

Comment: Краш трейсится именно в ядро luajit'а, при этом в чистой Lua 5.1 проблемы нет, выглядит как баг первого. На будущее — в C++ либо включайте`lua.hpp` (правильный путь), либо заключайте инклуды заголовков Lua в `extern C {}` (неправильный, но обычно рабочий путь). Проверьте на git версии luajit.

Comment: @val по поводу инклюдов - да, неуследил в этот раз.

Comment: @val тем не менее не могу подтвердить то, что при использовании lua5.1 все в порядке - тоже краш. Что интересно: lua5.3 крашится прямо на старте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96925/discussion-between-val-and-andrej-levkovitch).

Comment: Ошибка в строке `return (reinterpret_cast<float *>(ptr_) + sizeof(size_t))[i];` Когда в языке Си к указателю `float *` добавляется целое число, то при вычислении адреса это целое число умножается на размер `float` (т.е., на 4), и происходит выход за границы памяти, выделенной для этого массива.  Ошибка может не проявляться до поры до времени :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff точно! Как я мог так лажануть? Главное же знаю об этом! Спасибо, если оформите как ответ, приму